# Conemu - Highlighter - Detect custom strings via regex, and make them clickable (Jira Ticket Links)

Tags: conemu

A lot of the work I do is off Jira tickets, so one example is a git branch will be called something like ABC-1234, which is the Jira ticket ID.

I was wondering if there was any way to make a pattern match ([A-Z]{2,3}-\d+) in the console output
to be a clickable link to the ticket itself. Basically it would just have to take the found ticket ID and append it to a base URL

`http://jira.corp.com/browse/{ID}`

Thanks!
Justin

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the exact format of the ID, where in the ticket it appears, and what programming language (probably Java?) you want to use, but some variant on this regex should work:

([A-Z]+-[0-9]+)

This regex translates as, "match one or more capital letters A through Z, the literal dash character, and one or more digit characters 0 through 9".

Then append the captured group(s) to the base url. In Java, I think you'd want the StringBuilder append method.

Comment: I foolishly thought that the tag 'conemu' would fill in more context... that was silly!  updating question details. Appreciate the answer!

Comment: Ahhh thanks, StackExchange's algorithm sent me from the regex land in which I dwell... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯